# Is there a way to get a query return the users that the count of a certain condition is above a certain number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, where-clause

I am having trouble trying to figure the correct way to write an SQL query. Ok so let's say that we have three tables MyUser, Consult, Measurement. I would like to have a query that returns to me the users that have created more than 30 measurements in the past thirty days but haven't received a consult in the past 30 days. So far i have got something like this:

```
FROM MyUser a
where a.isActive = 1 AND a.email = 'test@gmail' AND a.userRole = 'patient'
having 30 < (select COUNT(*) From Measurement m, Consults c
        WHERE c.patient_email = 'test@gmail'
         AND m.patient_email = 'test@gmail'
         AND m.measurement_created_date BETWEEN '2020-07-20' AND '2020-10-20'
         AND NOT c.consult_created_date BETWEEN '2020-10-20'AND '2020-11-20')
```

This doesn't work properly.
Another aproach is:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Measurement m, MyUser a, Consults c
WHERE a.isActive = 1 AND a.email = 'test@gmail.com' AND a.userRole = 'patient'
AND c.patient_email = 'test@gmail'
AND m.patient_email = a.email
AND m.measurement_created_date BETWEEN '2020-08-10'AND '2020-09-10'
AND NOT c.consult_created_date BETWEEN '2020-08-10'AND '2020-19-10'
```

or something like that but this doesn't return the users and only returns the count. Can someone provide some guidance or solution to this? Thanks

Comment: In order to get a proper result, you need to write a proper query.  Please research how to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` properly.

Comment: Also this is year 2020.  Please learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: I don't see what your dates have to do with "the last 30 days".

Comment: The query is about understanding how I could have returned the wished result. The email and dates are just for  testing purposes because either way it will get modified to be used via java hibernate like that   
              ` "AND m.measurement_created_date 
                 BETWEEN :from AND :to " + 
                "AND NOT(c.consult_created_date BETWEEN :from AND :to) " 
                .setParameter("from", LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1))
                .setParameter("to", LocalDate.now()) `

Answer (score 0):

> a query that returns to me the users that have created more than 30 measurements in the past thirty days but haven't received a consult in the past 30 days

You could do this with subqueries. Your requirement literally translates as:

```
select *
from myuser u
where 
    (   
        select count(*)
        from measurement m
        where m.patient_email = u.email
          and m.measurement_created_date between '2020-07-20' and '2020-10-20'
    ) > 30
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from consults c
        where c.patient_email = u.email
          and m.consult_created_date between '2020-07-20' and '2020-10-20'
    )
```